# How to approach combining sequences and conditions in a natural style in Rx(Swift)

Tags: swift, system.reactive, rx-swift

I have 3 sequences to find out if I need to save changes to a text file:

1. **Text ID** (changed when showing another text; its presence also signifies "here's a note")
2. **Text editing status changes** (as a guard-clause, so to speak, to ensure the user is really editing and not just viewing the text)
3. **Content change** (when the user types into a text field)

The order in which elements are produced matters for the resulting combination. The list above represents the happy path.

A RxSwift/RxTest test case:

```
func testContentThenEditingThenChange_ProducesEdit() {

    let identifier = scheduler.createHotObservable([next(300, "identifier")])
    let isEditing = scheduler.createHotObservable([next(400, true)])
    let changedText = scheduler.createHotObservable([next(500, "foo")])

    let viewModel = TextEditingViewModel(
        identifier: identifer.asObservable(),
        changedText: changedText.asObservable(),
        isEditing: isEditing.asObservable())

    let result = scheduler.start { viewModel.textChange }

    XCTAssertEqual(result.events, [next(500, TextChange(identifier: "identifier", text: "foo"))])
}
```

How would you write this and keep the readability high?

Answer (score 1):

I can come up with 2 variants, both of which I don't like.

### FlatMap the 3 sequences in natural order

And so here's an implementation that does work.

```
struct TextEditingViewModel {

    let identifier: Observable<Identifier>
    let changedText: Observable<String>
    let isEditing: Observable<Bool>

    var textChange: Observable<TextChange> {
        return identifier
            .flatMap { identifier in self.isEditing.filter { $0 == true }.map { _ in identifier } }
            .flatMap { identifier in self.changedText.map { text in (identifier, text) } }
            .map { identifier, text in TextChange(identifier: identifier, text: text) }
    }
}
```

Flat-mapping and putting the outer sequences value into the combination is a very roundabout approach. I discovered this solution only thanks to the tests. My initial approach was to use `withLatestFrom`, mostly because the resulting code reads like the story I want to tell:

### WithLatestFrom, Yoda-style

In natural order, this does not produce a result as intended:

```
// Does not work!
var textChange: Observable<TextChange> {
    return identifier
        .withLatestFrom(isEditing.filter { $0 == true }) { identifier, _ in identifier }
        .withLatestFrom(identifier) { _, identifier in identifier }
        .withLatestFrom(changedText) { identifier, text in (identifier, text) }
        .map { identifier, text in TextChange(identifier: identifier, text: text) }
}
```

If I stick to `withLatestFrom` because it reveals more intent than `flatMap`, I have to write the sequence combination in Yoda-style, that is: backwards.

```
var textChange: Observable<TextChange> {

    return changedText
        .withLatestFrom(isEditing.filter { $0 == true }) { text, _ in text }
        .withLatestFrom(identifier) { text, identifier in (identifier, text) }
        .map { identifier, text in Edit(identifier: identifier, text: text) }
}
```

So instead of the "natural" case of "when you have an identifier and are editing and then a text change comes in, produce an element", I tell the story from the end "when a text change comes in, only if you were editing, if you were having an identifier, then produce an element".